# How to create component for static navigationOptions in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, mobile

I want create navigationOptions in all component is same with props like below but not work:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => { 
    return (<NavigationOptions title: 'Sales Report'/>) 
};

class NavigationOptions extends Component { 
    render() { 
        return ({ title: this.props.title }) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error statement? If so, please post the error.

Comment: not have any error but NavigationOptions not return object { title: this.props.title }